# i can not fetch data to another page using mongo atlas in node.js always show error message cannot read property of function

Tags: node.js

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at User.getCart (D:\udamNode\models\user.js:49:40)
    at exports.getCart (D:\udamNode\controllers\shop.js:55:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\udamNode\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

**Model file method**

```
getCart() {
const db = getDb();
const productIds = this.cart.items.map(i => {
  return i.productId;
});
return db.collection('products').find({ _id: { $in: productIds } }).toArray().then(products => {
    return products.map(p => {
      return {
        ...p,
        quantity: this.cart.items.find(i => {
          return i.productId.toString() === p._id.toString();
        }).quantity
      };
    });
  });
```

}

**Controller file method**

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {req.user.getCart().then(products => {
  res.render('shop/cart', {
    path: '/cart',
    pageTitle: 'Your Cart',
    products: products
  });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

};

Comment: could You please preserve line numbers in User.js or say what line is 49?

Comment: @AndreiPiatrou line no 49 is     const productIds = this.cart.items.map(i => {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code provided above `this.cart.items` is `undefined`. this mean that when `user` is fetched the result object does not include `cart.items` in the query result payload.

So in case of mongodb one of the following ways should help:

1. `items` nested models have to be included when `user` is queried from the DB
2. `cart` with its `items` should be queried with an additional query in `getCart()` method first.